# How many "friendly NPC" kills until the game can no longer be finished?

Tags: fallout-4

I would like to shoot dead every NPC with stupid dialog or fetch quest but every other NPC around just tries to kill me immediately (only tried this in Diamond City and those security guards are tough).

Has anybody tried that and succeeded in making it a somehow playable/fun game? How many "friendly NPC" kills until the game can no longer be finished?

Comment: Just use console commands or mods, if the game's not fun enough.

Comment: Speculation, but with new vegas, deliberate actions were taken to ensure you could kill all killable NPCs, and still win the game. Im sure Bethesda would use the same logic with 4.

Comment: Not sure how a game can be playable and fun when practically every NPC will be hostile to you. At a minimum, you'd have to somehow avoid making main storyline quest-givers unavailable to you. Bethesda is good at making sure that you can't kill bare-essential NPCs (and then some), but that doesn't mean you might not piss them off to the point of being unusable. Avoiding this will especially become difficult as you're very likely to encounter situations where you'll have to fight other NPCs in the presence of essentials who might not appreciate that.

Comment: @Timelord64 In some previous Bethesda games, like Morrowind, you could kill essential NPCs, and were then given a message informing you that the game was no longer completable. Also, New Vegas was done by Obsidian, so Bethesda might do things a little differently in house.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify "somehow playable and FUN game". That doesn't have an objective meaning. What aspect of what you've tried didn't match this? What are you even asking?

Comment: @DCShannon, I believe it was that they had learnt from Morrowind. Oblivion has the same preventative means, but it is simply that essential NPCs can not die.

Comment: I really don't get why this questsion has been bombarded with downvotes.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC Because it's unclear. I actually flagged it for closing.

Comment: Unclear? I disagree. Unless you haven't played the game and therefore don't know how the game works at all... which is not grounds for closing. A question that can have interesting answers like this one (and it does, read below) deserves an edit before it deservers getting taken out back and shot.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC It would probably be fine if the sentence "Has anybody tried that and succeeded in making it a somehow playable/fun game?" were deleted. I don't want to change the asker's intent though. Anytime the primary question in a question is inherently subjective in nature, the question is unclear. Putting the question on hold is not taking it out back and shooting it. The intent is to stop answers while it's edited.

Comment: BTW: The question somehow arose after reading this https://www.reddit.com/r/FalloutMods/comments/3u5bgl/gauging_interest_in_a_fallout_4_content_rewrite/ especially the analysis.

I love Witcher series and literally spent over 300 hours of blissful gaming. Compared to Last of the Bethesda games, the game just seems dull.

I found this interesting thought about Bethesda games

Comment: BTW2: I found these thoughts about Bethesda games interesting
http://reddit.com/r/Games/comments/3v9jc8/playing_the_psychopath/

Comment: So, someone apparently went on a "kill everyone" rampage in FO3 and was successful. Granted, he couldn't kill Essentials. But he did at least make sure to knock them all down so he could claim a "kill". https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwH1xJhcXG0cTar29Rjigyyb5tWX4rMdb And he's done the same for FO:NV too. He's also done a "YOLO" run of FO:NV and is working through the same for FO3. So, "kill everyone" in FO4 may similarly be possible. Everyone's got doubts about a YOLO run though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPCs marked as 'essential' to the main quest/storyline will not die when you 'kill' them. They will drop to the ground when killed, and get up with full health again. This is similar to how followers will act when taking fatal amounts of damage (except you need to Stim followers to revive them while within combat).

In other words, you can go on a killing frenzy if you wish without repercussions to the main story. However:

- **You will miss out on some side quests.**

  - Side quests given by killed NPCs are usually inaccessible. There may be other ways to trigger the quest (such as finding a holotape or reading info on a terminal), but this is not always the case.
- **The game will most likely be harder to complete (but not impossible)**

  - Previously neutral or allied settlements will become hostile, making it hard to find safe places to store loot, rest up, barter or fast travel to, at least for a while.
  - Unkillable story-based NPCs will likely remain hostile for a long period, so you will have to wait until they become non-hostile again before interacting with them.
- **Most non-named NPCs will respawn anyway**

  - Settlers, Guards and other townsfolk will respawn after a while, meaning it's more likely that when you revisit to talk to a Quest NPC, there will still be a living town wandering around, making the 'point' of the kill frenzy a bit null and void.

Whether or not this is 'fun' is really a moot point. Fallout 4 is built to be as open-world as possible, with the only restrictions placed on the 'absolutely essential' main story NPCs. If this is how you want to play the game, that is perfectly fine. Remember, you can always load a previous save if you find that you wish to revert any of your wanton destruction.

Comment: Will the story-based NPCs actually become non-hostile at some point? What's the criteria? Without this, the game will be impossible (or very close to it) to complete. Also, you don't *need* to Stimpack a follower to revive them. They'll come back on their own. You just need to clear the zone of enemies yourself. Lastly, do guards and settlers not carry their hostility over a respawn? You'd think that once you've slain a town (or most of it) the groups responsible for protecting it would have you on a watchlist or something.

Comment: @Iszi - a) Yes, I'm not sure of the exact criteria but it seems to be a couple of in-game days, up to a week in some cases b) I didn't realise Followers got back up out of combat, I've only had one follower go down and I stimmed them right away. I've amended this sentence. c) You'd think there'd be a watchlist, but there isnt - same with unkillable NPCs, you need to wait a week or so without visiting the place for the cell to reload.